# Prove that $2^\aleph+\aleph$ equals $2^\aleph$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

How do I show this elegantly? 
I can't seem to find the right sets for it...
Maybe there are some substantial laws I could use? 
I would appreciate your help...

What I said is: $2^\mathfrak c$ is for sure greater than $\mathfrak c$. Furthermore, $$2^\mathfrak c\cdot 2^\mathfrak c=2^\mathfrak c+\mathfrak c = 2^\mathfrak c.$$ On the other hand, $$2^\mathfrak c\cdot 2^\mathfrak c= 2^\mathfrak c+\underbrace{(2^\mathfrak c+\ldots+2^\mathfrak c)}_{2^\mathfrak c -1\text{ times}}$$ which is greater than $2^\mathfrak c+(\mathfrak c+\ldots+\mathfrak c)$ ($2^\mathfrak c - 1$ times) which is greater then $2^\mathfrak c+\mathfrak c$, which means $2^\mathfrak c$ is larger then $2^\mathfrak c+\mathfrak c$.

Together with $2^\mathfrak c+\mathfrak c$ being larger then $2^\mathfrak c$, we get, by Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem that $2^\mathfrak c+\mathfrak c=2^\mathfrak c$.

Any corrections?

Comment: How many elements are in the power set of a set with n elements?

Comment: I'm amused. Most people think that $\aleph$ is denoting some arbitrary cardinal, but it really denotes the cardinal of the continuum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ 2^\aleph = 2^{\aleph+1} = 2 \cdot 2^\aleph = 2^ \aleph + 2^\aleph \ge 2^ \aleph + \aleph \ge 2^ \aleph $$

and this proves from Cantor–Schroeder–Bernstein theorem.

Comment: Elegantly played, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

On the one hand, $2^\aleph\leq\aleph+2^\aleph$. On the other hand, you can show quite easily that because $\aleph+\aleph=\aleph$ we have that $2^\aleph\cdot 2^\aleph=2^\aleph$, and therefore $2^\aleph+2^\aleph=2^\aleph$ as well.

Now using Cantor-Bernstein you have $$\aleph+2^\aleph\leq2^\aleph+2^\aleph=2^\aleph$$

Note that proving this with specific sets is not elegant. It's never elegant. Cardinal arithmetic is the elegant part here, and proving the first volley of theorems of cardinal arithmetic is rarely "elegant", and mostly exercise in composing bijections and injections. But then you get to use it for particular cases like here, and end up with quick proofs for something that is otherwise tedious and annoying.

As for what you have written, while not incorrect, it requires the use of the axiom of choice to prove that cardinal multiplication is just like repeated addition infinitely many times; it is also considered the far less elegant solution. Your mind is in the right place, but the execution is lacking. While for finite cardinals we can, and sometimes should, replace the product by sums it is rarely the case for infinite cardinals.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, Asaf. You are right... I actually think it was a bit silly of me to ask this question, because it was pretty trivial and I was just being lazy, or really tired. 
I guess that's my time to get some sleep.

Comment: עדיין מוקדם, ומחר יום שישי... :-)

Comment: אכן אבל כנראה שבשבילי כבר מאוחר
לפחות שישי מחר (: 
שבת שלום=]

Answer (score 1):

Your edit makes the question trivial for infinite $\aleph$. It remains false for finite $\aleph$.

Comment: Sorry
I edited it

Comment: Yeah is does, but it still awaits a direct proof...
How is mine? Any obtainments?